# No Sellers for stock , Buyers bidding on higher price - why price going up?

Tags: stocks

For past 2 days , I am seeing stocks where Buyers bid on very high price and no seller is there in the stock market . The price of the stock rises.
Whats this strategy to earn money ?

I want to add a snapshot to make this clear, but I can't find any option to add a picture.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really the result of a deliberate strategy (most of the time). In this case, there are no sellers, i.e. the stock at the moment is worth more to a potential seller than is currently being offered by the market. That means the price must rise to entice the potential sellers to part with their stocks.

Suppose you had bought a stock and you think it's a great company, easily worth $10. As long as you continue to think it's worth $10 you're probably not going to sell it for less than that, even if the market price is below that. However, if the market went some way above that, say $15 or $20 then you'd be likely to sell your $10 stock and bank the profit.

Answer (score 0):

when the demand is high, so in this case the bid price raises, the price get high too. Moreover there's no seller-side offer, so the price necessarily must raise.